# ANT: Failed to process the request successfully. Cause(UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION): INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: No package named 'Retrieve1Objectpkg' found

Tags: salesforcedx, ant

I keep getting the above error. I am trying to retrieve one custom object and the CLI keeps saying that the package is not found. Based on the prompts, it seems that I need to have a value for package parameter.

Here is the package.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Retrieve1Objectpkg</fullName>
    <types>
        <members>Exchange_Connections__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

Here is the build.xml

```
<target name="Retrieve1Object">
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieve1Object" packageNames="Retrieve1Objectpkg"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `retrieve1Object` is a valid file directory.

If it isn't you can either create it manually or add `<mkdir dir="retrieve1object"/>` under the first `<target...>` tag

[Sauce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_retrieve_unpackaged.htm)

Comment: That didn't work. I am trying to retrieve one custom object and the packageName is required. So I created the file directory and the package.xml in the folder Retrieve1Objectpkg.

Answer (score 1):

`sf:retrieve ... packageNames=...` is used to retrieve the metadata in a package. To retrieve some metadata that does not originate from a package, you would use:
`sf:retrieve ... unpackaged="<path to your package.xml>"`.

And I've never specified a  in my `package.xml`, you could try without as well.

Comment: The path parameter worked!